# Configuring two AD LDS instances to synchronize with one another

Tags: synchronization, ad-lds

I'm trying to find information on synchronizing multiple AD LDS instances with each other, but all the information I'm finding via Google is about synchronizing AD LDS to AD DS.

I would appreciate it if anyone could point me toward some articles on how to configure two AD LDS instances to synchronize with one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I believe you want to do is AD LDS Replication:

See the following article:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d4b4004-9f26-4545-a1e4-8e527102f0a7